# Set Array of index value from database

Tags: ios, sqlite, uibutton, indexing, nsmutablearray

I have id value and product_image value in database. Image is associated with id value. I'm setting productimg_array image values to buttons for click. SO, here i need to set the id value to this button.So, i'm uisng for loop. If i use int i=0 the images are displaying, but if i set int i= cat_iamgeId the images are not displaying. Why? How to assign the id value as a index

```
-(void)actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex {


    if (buttonIndex >=0 && buttonIndex < [categoryIds count]) {

        NSInteger categoryId = [categoryIds[buttonIndex] intValue];


      NSLog(@"button is %d",buttonIndex);

        NSLog(@"categoryId is %ld", (long)categoryId);

        productimg_array = [[NSMutableArray array]init];

        descript_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] ;

        cat_imageidArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image,order_by,description FROM product where cat_id = ?";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.




            if (sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, categoryId) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSLog(@"%s: bind failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {





                cat_iamgeId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);


                NSLog(@"cat_iamgeId is %ld",(long)cat_iamgeId);

                [cat_imageidArray addObject:@(cat_iamgeId)];




                product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
               // NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);

                [productimg_array addObject:product_image];






                descript = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

             //   NSLog(@"descript is %@",descript);


                [descript_array addObject:descript];



           }


        }
```

For loop for UIButton click:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {






       NSLog(@"productimg_array_index %@", cat_imageidArray[i]);





            imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

            Width = Width + 20+(i*74);




              imgView1.tag = i;

              NSLog(@"product id is %ld ", (long)imgView1.tag);


            [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


            [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];



            [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];






        }
```

NSlog tag value:

```
product id is 202 
 product id is 203 
 product id is 204 
 product id is 205 
 clicked
 button 202 is clicked.
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 202 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

imgView1 click: (dbsofaclicked:)

```
-(void)dbsofaClicked:(id)sender{


   NSLog(@"clicked");


    NSLog(@"button %d is clicked.", [sender tag]);

          mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];


    [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


    [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {



    }];

    [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]];

    [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
}
```

Comment: No. Not this, if id value is in database 66,67,68 etc. I'm fetching from database and assign cat_iamgeId. I need to set 66,67,68 whatever id value to index start i. I don't want to start index as 0. Is it possible?

Comment: Your `NSRangeException` is caused by the fact that you're using the `[sender tag]`, which is the product id (202) as the index in your array (i.e. asking for the 202nd item in an array that only has four items). Rather than the internal product id, did you mean to set the tag to be some counter (i.e. values 0 through 3) for your tag?

Comment: @Rob: you only solved this issue couple of months back. Can you come to chat? one small issue.I can't find. please

Comment: The problem is i'm using single tap for displays description value from database for each categoryIds. If i click sofa button it start index value 0,1,2,so on. And click table button it start 0,1,2. So, if table description is not coming proper because of index value resetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much better way to do this. Use one array to hold the data for each product image.

```
NSMutableArray *image_array = [NSMutableArray array];

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    cat_imageId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
    product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
    [image_array addObject:@{ "id" : @(cat_imageId), @"url" : product_image }];
    NSLog(@"cat_imageId is %ld",(long)cat_imageId);
    NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);
}
```

This creates an array of dictionaries. This keeps the data for each image together. This allows you to sort the data if needed and you only have one array to deal with.

Then your code to create the buttons becomes (based on your update):

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < image_array.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *image_data = image_array[i];

    UIButton *imgView1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];
    Width = Width + 20 + (i * 74);

    imgView1.tag = i;
    [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image_data[@"url"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];
}
```

Comment: your code is correct. check my edited code. I have click the imgView1 button. If i click i got error for index. Here having the problem

Comment: OK, based on your updated code you never actually need the "id" from the database table, just the URL. Set the tag to the array index, not the image `id`.

Comment: My code is big process. Can you come chat, i will explain. I tried last one week

Comment: How can i display same tag value with mmageView?

Comment: Your code already sets the tag of `mmageView` to the same tag as the button.

Comment: I updated my answer. Keep in mind that the tag of the button or the image view can be used to get the image id if needed.

Comment: See my edited question. What i have facing the problem. I have action sheet with button. when i click the sofa button it displays the images from database table index start from 0,1 etc. then if i click the table button it displays the table images from database then index start from 0,1,2 etc. This is the problem. Same index value coming for sofa, table images.

Comment: I'm getting tag value from id is product id is 202 
 product id is 203 
 product id is 204 
 product id is 205. If i click imgView1 button i need to set these product id. But i'm getting index 0,1,2. Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43003/discussion-between-user3073276-and-rmaddy)